# How to avoid this kind of Annoying Windows Security Messages?

Tags: windows-7

I am always getting "windows security" messages as shown in the below screenshot. not only a single PC but all other PCs which are connected to the same router also getting the same message. Is there anyone have idea on how to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: at least you should let us know what is wpad.domain.name in your network ?

Comment: are you using Automatic Proxy Detection in either of your browsers? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol